# Forging in IIslands of War

Tags: iislands-of-war

Since the game is new and difficult to find, not many people play it and as a result there are no guides for the same.
Could anyone figure out how to forge each craftable item in the game?

Comment: I do not have the reputation to make a new tag, could anyone add a tag IIslands of War and I'll edit it?

Comment: Do you mean [Islands of War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfsQV-ySreI)?

Comment: @Ben Nope the game is called IIslands of War

Comment: Yeah, you misspelled it the first time (as did I, I noticed).

Comment: I think the **II**slands, is meant to be roman numerals for two (as it's the sequel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forging in IIslands of War is a bit of a "recipe" mechanic. You require three base items to combine, with some money, to make a new item.

[image: Forging a new Warp Drive]

[image: Forging a new Double Mortar]

Similar to Minecraft, there does not seem to be any in-game "recipe book" to figure out what each item needs to make it, but if this game gets a wiki, it will likely list all of the recipes. The only restriction I have been able to identify so far though is that each item has a "status", in terms of rarity or level. This post talks about "legendary" equipment:

> are legendary items the best you can currently get? (In terms of weaponry)
>   [image]